# How to prevent recursive in copying files and dirs?

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I bumped into the problem with copying files/dirs. Been struggling almost for whole day.
I have to copy from root dir files and its dires with files and subdirs.
Actually, i've made something. However, every time i run in the stackoverflow error.

```
abstract class SystemOperations {
    public virtual void SearchFiles() { }
    public virtual void SearchDirectories() { }

    public abstract void CreateDirectory(string DIR);
    public abstract void CloneContent(string DIR);
    public abstract void CreateJSON(string DIR);

    public void ExecuteCopying(string DIR) {
        CreateDirectory(DIR);
        CloneContent(DIR);
        CreateJSON(DIR);
    }
}

class FileOperations : SystemOperations {
    DirectoryInfo _MainPath;
    public DirectoryInfo MainPath {
        get { return _MainPath; }
        set { _MainPath = value; }
    }

    public FileOperations(DirectoryInfo MainPath) {
        this.MainPath = MainPath;
    }

    #region Unnecessary for current task
    public override void SearchFiles() {
        string path = "";
        FileInfo[] files = MainPath.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
            path = file.Name;
        }
    }

    public override void SearchDirectories() {
        string path = "";
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = MainPath.GetDirectories();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories) {
            path = directory.Name;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public override void CreateDirectory(string DIR) {
        string newFolder = Path.Combine(MainPath + "", DIR);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
    }

    public override void CloneContent(string DIR) {

        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath + "")) {
            string dir = Path.GetFileName(directory);

            CloneContent(Path.Combine(MainPath + "", dir));
        }

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(MainPath + "")) {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(MainPath + "", Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
        }
    }

    public override void CreateJSON(string DIR) {
        if (!Directory.Exists(DIR)) {
            var asd = new DirectoryInfo(DIR);
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        SystemOperations task = new FileOperations(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\LAK"));
        task.ExecuteCopying("COPY");
    }
}
```

So, the function CloneContent has to copy in each dir/subdirs files. But its recursive func and as i written above, i run to the error. And dont know how to fix this one. Thank u!

Comment: When using recursion you need a break out clause. There must be a scenario where you don't recurse. Here's an example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/.  In this case you exit the function if the entered value is less than 2.

Comment: `foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath + ""))` should be `...GetDirectories(DIR))`

Comment: Your `Search...` functions don't make sense, they don't do anything. `MainPath + ""` is the same as `MainPath`. Also `_mainPath` can be removed by making it an auto-property.

Comment: @Charlieface No, `MainPath + ""` is the same as `MainPath.ToString()` (`MainPath` is a `DirectoryInfo` instance). However it should be noted that [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring?view=net-5.0) states that the `FullName` property should be used instead.

Comment: @Charlieface `MainPath` is not a string, though. It's a `DirectoryInfo` object. If you were to do `Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath)`, you'd get a compile error. You need to do `Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath.FullName)` or `Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath.ToString())` or as they did, `Directory.GetDirectories(MainPath + "")`. Even better yet, since it's a `DirectoryInfo` object: `MainPath.GetDirectories()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some kind of problem with the way you are trying to determine which directory you need to search next, the use of MainPath looks wrong to me.

Personally i also always prefer to have a secondary stop condition to avoid a StackOverflowException, like the maxrunCount i use below.

If you want a recursive directory lookup you should rewrite your code to something like

```
void Main()
{
    string MainPath = "D:\\LAK";
    // unless your directory is actually named \LAK:) you should use either @"D:\LAK" or "d:\\LAK"
    CloneContent(MainPath,1000);
}

public void CloneContent(string directoryToSearch, int maxrunCount)
{
    if(maxrunCount==0)
        return;
        
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(directoryToSearch);
    string[] directories = null;
    try
    {
        directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryToSearch);
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"No access to dir {directoryToSearch}");
        directories = new string[0];
    }
    
    // ensure you have access to the current directoryToSearch
    foreach (var directory in directories)
    {
        CloneContent(directory,--maxrunCount);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"cloning {directoryToSearch}");
    // .... do the actual cloning here, 
    // you will end up here when there are no more subdirectories on the current branch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive method to work, it must have at least one "exit" condition - the point at which it's done its job and can unwind the stack. In our case, it would be when there are no more direcories or files to copy from the source to the destination.

One way of writing this method would take in a source directory and a destination directory, and then it can recursively call itself for each sub-directory:

```
public static void CloneContent(string sourceDir, string destDir)
{
    // If the source directory doesn't exist, return
    if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDir)) return;
    
    // Create destination if needed
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir);

    // Copy files from this directory to the new path
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
    }

    // Recursively call this method for each sub directory
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
    {
        string dirName = Path.GetFileName(subDir);
        string newSource = Path.Combine(sourceDir, dirName);
        string newDest = Path.Combine(destDir, dirName);

        CloneContent(newSource, newDest);
    }
}
```